# Blog post redirects without the /dd/ in the URL are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, redirection

Links to the blog that use the format `https://stackoverflow.blog/yyyy/mm/post-title` instead of `https://stackoverflow.blog/yyyy/mm/dd/post-title` are no longer redirecting properly to the intended article.

Given how many times the blog has changed platforms and systems, including the format of links, maintaining redirects is no simple task but should be kept up. As an example, the blog posts linked in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/294691) are no longer redirecting. The blog post announcing the arrival of JNat and animuson is linked as https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/04/jnat-and-animuson-workin-on-ur-problemz/. This results in an error:

[image: 404 "Oops! Something bad happened!" error at that URL]

Searching through the blog, I can find the post properly at https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/04/22/jnat-and-animuson-workin-on-ur-problemz/. Another example is the blog post about [pro-tem mods](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), also linked in that past and resulting in a 404.

Checking the Wayback Machine, I can confirm that these redirects [did used to work properly](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506171419/https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/04/jnat-and-animuson-workin-on-ur-problemz/).

Can these redirects please be fixed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Great find; I was unaware of that legacy URL format. Those URLs should be restored now.