# Blog links to /category pages are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, broken-link

Related but not the same issue: [Blog post redirects without the /dd/ in the URL are broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392671)

This link: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

Should correctly lead to a list of blog posts with the "cc-wiki-dump" keyword. The correct new format is: https://stackoverflow.blog/cc-wiki-dump

Instead it leads to https://stackoverflow.blog/category/cc-wiki-dump/ which shows a 404 page.

This is the case for apparently all links to /category. It affects [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ablog.stackoverflow.com%2Fcategory) as well as tag wikis like [data-dump](/questions/tagged/data-dump) that feature the old style link.

For ease of comparison:

```
Link    : https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/
Expected: https://stackoverflow.blog/cc-wiki-dump/
Actual  : https://stackoverflow.blog/category/cc-wiki-dump/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the report - these are now fixed and redirecting properly.

Comment: Thanks for the responsiveness on these reports!